# How does a ReactiveCocoa interval timer produce this effect?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I'm learning ReactiveCocoa, and am stumped by the following:

If I bind this signal to a label:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RAC(self.currentTimeLabel, text) = self.timeAgoSignal;
}

-(RACSignal *)timeAgoSignal{
    return [[[RACSignal interval:1 onScheduler:[RACScheduler scheduler]] startWith:[NSDate date]] map:^id (NSDate *value) {
        NSLog (@"Value: %@", value);
        return value.description;
    }];
}
```

First of all, the label doesn't update (I'm not concerned about this, I can probably work out why). My main question is: how does the block log an updated date on each tick?

```
Value: 2014-08-16 09:15:40 +0000
Value: 2014-08-16 09:15:41 +0000
Value: 2014-08-16 09:15:42 +0000
Value: 2014-08-16 09:15:43 +0000
```

This is amazing to me. If I had a timer output an [NSDate date], it would of course not change on each tick:

```
-(instancetype)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _date = [NSDate date];

        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector (output) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)output{
    NSLog (@"Date: %@", self.date);
}
```

Output:

```
Date: 2014-08-16 09:19:36 +0000
Date: 2014-08-16 09:19:36 +0000
Date: 2014-08-16 09:19:36 +0000
Date: 2014-08-16 09:19:36 +0000
```

Which is the expected behaviour.

If the `startWith:[NSDate date]` was in a block which was called anew on each tick, then I could understand. But it's not:

For instance, if I instead use `startWith:[self date]`, I can see that `[self date]` is called only once, so it's not magically calling that method each time, again as expected.

No code that I can see is incrementing the date manually. So how is this occurring?

Comment: I actually fixed the "not updating the label" bit: I needed to append `deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]` to the signal, so that the UI would actually redraw. More details [at the bottom of this post](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/getting-started-with-reactivecocoa/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Let's take apart your code.

If you were to augment your logging code slightly to the following:

```
NSLog (@"Value(%p): %@", value, value);
```

Then what you would see is the pointer of the `value` object. Every time the block is involved, a new `NSDate` instance is being generated and sent as a value. `NSDate` objects are immutable, after all.

OK, so on to your question: how is this happening? Well, the benefit of ReactiveCocoa is that its open source, so we don't have to guess what's going on. The [code](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/9c9912f64e994af45a9adbb6306d2a101f2cbbe3/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.m#L712-L721) that sets up the repetition actually uses the scheduler you pass in. Let's take a look at [that code](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/6d49c6fe319856757f2ec14e3d970ec92d8dca6a/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACQueueScheduler.m#L80-L98).

```
uint64_t intervalInNanoSecs = (uint64_t)(interval * NSEC_PER_SEC);
uint64_t leewayInNanoSecs = (uint64_t)(leeway * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, self.queue);
dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, [self.class wallTimeWithDate:date], intervalInNanoSecs, leewayInNanoSecs);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
dispatch_resume(timer);

return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
    dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
    dispatch_release(timer);
}];
```

So the scheduler just uses GCD in order to set up recurring block invocations with new `NSDate` instances every time.

So the last piece of the puzzle is the use of `startWith:`. `interval:scheduler:` sets up a signal that fires its first event after `interval` seconds. Until then, the signal hasn't sent anything and the value of your text field would be `nil`. So we use `startWith:` in order to kick off the signal and get it to send a value immediately.

Comment: ah ha! Because I was so confused I didn't frame my question correctly, but the last part of your answer made it click. What I was wrongly assuming was that somehow the `[NSDate date]` object was being kept around and incremented (and, as you say, they're supposed to be immutable), and I couldn't find code for that. What I didn't cotton on to is that the `NSDate*` passed through to `map:` was actually coming from `interval:onScheduler:` (though now it's obvious: this must be the purpose. I thought it was only a timer), and the startsWith: parameter just loads an *initial* value. Thanks Ash.